# minimum number of bits required to perfectly hash/map ChessBoard pawns occupancy

Tags: information-theory, hash-function, chessboard

What is the minimum (and how to calculate it?) number of bits required to perfectly hash/map pawn occupancy with black and white pawns treated differently (meaning a position with black pawns and white pawns doesn't equal the same position with the colors inverted)?

-1st comment: a square is either occupied by a black pawn or a white pawn or is empty, so I guess? three states.

-2nd comment: Both cases.

-1st answer: by the way optimization is highly important.

Comment: How many different states are there per square? How many squares are on a chessboard? From these two facts, it's not too hard to figure out how many total states the board can have, and from there how many bits it takes to encode all possible configurations.

Comment: It may be possible to do better than encoding the state of each square individually using run length encoding, or specifying the positions of the pawns, but in general (with up to 64 of either type of pawn allowed), looking at the number of possible configurations is a simpler way to start.

Comment: Are you looking at all possible arrangements of $8$ black and $8$ white pawns on an $8\times 8$ chessboard, or only at the ones that are attainable starting from all pawns on the $2$nd rank and following the laws of chess?